# Video face recognition, flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

Recently I have been working on a Flutter app, and I need to do a facial recognition, inside the app, that captures a face that was recorded in a video. But I can't find anywhere that can help me.

I have already tried mlKit, firebase_ml_vision, flutter_face_recognition, and some other technologies, in none of them did I get the flutter to detect a recorded face.

My codes, the first one, is the controller, and the second, is the main class

```
    class FaceDetectorController {

  pickVideo(File video) async {
    final FirebaseVisionImage visionImage = FirebaseVisionImage.fromFile(video);
    print('VisionImage: $video');

    final FaceDetectorOptions faceDetectorOptions = FaceDetectorOptions(
      enableTracking: true,
      enableLandmarks: true,
      enableContours: false,
      enableClassification: true,
      minFaceSize: 0.1,
      mode: FaceDetectorMode.accurate,
    );

    final FaceDetector faceDetector =
        FirebaseVision.instance.faceDetector(faceDetectorOptions);

    faceDetector.processImage(visionImage);

    final List<Face> faces = await faceDetector.processImage(visionImage);
    print('Quantidade de Faces: ${faces.length}');

    for (Face face in faces) {
      var boundingBox = face.boundingBox;
      final double rotY = face.headEulerAngleY;
      final double rotZ = face.headEulerAngleZ;
      print('Rotação do Rosto: $rotY, $rotZ');

      if (face.trackingId != null) {
        final int id = face.trackingId;
        print('Rosto: $id');
      }

      final FaceLandmark leftEar = face.getLandmark(FaceLandmarkType.leftEar);
      if (leftEar != null) {
        var leftEarPos = leftEar.position;
        print('posição da orelha esquerda: ${leftEarPos}');
      }

      if (face.smilingProbability != null) {
        var smileProb = face.smilingProbability;
        print('Sorrindo: $smileProb');
      }

      if (face.leftEyeOpenProbability != null) {
        var leftEyeOpen = face.leftEyeOpenProbability;
        print('Olho Esquerdo aberto: $leftEyeOpen');
      }
      if (face.rightEyeOpenProbability != null) {
        var rightEyeOpen = face.rightEyeOpenProbability;
        print('Olho Direito aberto: $rightEyeOpen');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:firebase_ml_vision/firebase_ml_vision.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app_face/face_detector_controller.dart';

class MyFaceDetectorView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyFaceDetectorViewState createState() => _MyFaceDetectorViewState();
}

class _MyFaceDetectorViewState extends State<MyFaceDetectorView> {
  final _picker = ImagePicker();
  File _imageFile;
  File _videoFile;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          "Detector de Face",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: myFaceView(),
    );
  }

  myFaceView() {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child: Container(
                  child: Column(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Text(
                      "Selecione um arquivo",
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        child: CircleAvatar(
                          child: IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.video_library),
                            onPressed: () async => pickVideo(),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 18),
                    child: RaisedButton(
                      child: Text("Escanear", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
                      onPressed: scanner,
                      color: Colors.orange,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  scanner() {
    List<Face> faces;

    if (faces != null) {
      return _alert();
    } else {
      FaceDetectorController faceDetec = FaceDetectorController();
      faceDetec.pickVideo(_videoFile);
      print("escaneado");
    }
  }

  Future<void> _alert() {
    return showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Nenhum rosto encontrado'),
          content: const Text(
              'Não encontramos nada no seu arquivo, tente novamente.'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('Ok'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  pickImage() async {
    final PickedFile picFile =
        await _picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    setState(() {
      this._imageFile = File(picFile.path);
    });
/*
Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
  child: CircleAvatar(
    child: IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.insert_photo),
        onPressed: () async => pickImage(),
        ),
      ),
   ),

*/
  }

  pickVideo() async {
    //final videoFile = await FilePicker.getFile(type: FileType.video);
    final PickedFile videoFile = await _picker.getVideo(
      source: ImageSource.gallery,
      maxDuration: Duration(seconds: 5),
    );

    setState(() {
      this._videoFile = File(videoFile.path);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please edit your post: add a question you;d like to ask and tell us what exactly did you expect from this code and what happened instead. What problems did you run into? Any error messages, or unexpected behavior?

Comment: Thank you very much.

I researched on the internet how to do facial recognition in a video, as I said, but I need to do this project. I would like you to help me, saying if there is any class, or package that helps me to recognize faces within a video. Is there anything I can change in my project, to do this facial recognition?

Comment: So what is your code doing and what problem with your code are you experiencing?

Comment: my code has no errors. Only on the Debug Console, when you press the "escanear" button, it shows this:

E / flutter (31345): [ERROR: flutter / lib / ui / ui_dart_state.cc (166)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException (error, Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth ()' on a null object reference, null)

In addition to not scanning the file selected by the user.

Can you help me with that? Thank you very much.

Comment: What was your outcome? Were you able to achieve it for recorded video? if yes, how? 

Please let us know..
thanks